# jquery validate plugin custom error class assigned to parent div

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that Im validating with jQuery validate pluging.

This is my jQuery code for validating:

```
$('#authForm').validate({
                rules: {
                    Email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    Password: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    PasswordAgain: {
                        equalTo: "#Password"
                    },
                    Name: {
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                errorClass: "invalid",
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) { }
            });
```

I have added an errorClass that I need to append to a parent div, not to the input field:

The HTML structure of one of the fields are like this:

```
<div class="form-group form-group-custom ">
    <label>Email Address</label>
    <input name="Email" type="text" class="form-control invalid" value="test@test.com" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="Email-error" aria-invalid="true">
</div>
```

And if you notice the "`invalid`" class has been appended to the input element that actually is correct, but I need to append it to my `<div class="form-group form-group-custom">` and also remove it when the validation is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`highlight`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#highlight) and `unhighlight` functions are always used to apply/remove any classes when things go valid/invalid.  Simply write custom jQuery DOM traversal functions that [target your parent `div`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/).

```
$('#authForm').validate({
    rules: {
        ....
    },
    ....
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).parent('div').addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).parent('div').addClass(validClass).removeClass(errorClass);
    },
    ....
```

If the classes need to be completely separate from the classes that are automatically applied by the plugin, then instead of using the keywords that represent the pre-set classes, use different classes renamed as you wish.

```
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).parent('div').addClass('myerrorclass').removeClass('myvalidclass');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).parent('div').addClass('myvalidclass').removeClass('myerrorclass');
    },
```