# jQuery Validate plugin one field required, but not both

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that I'm validating with jQuery Validate plugin and I would like only one field to be filled out, while the other will have a 0 (zero) value.  However, it must be mandatory that one or the other be filled out.

Here is my actual form:

[image]

This is my form HTML:

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label> <span>Amount to Player</span></label>
                    <input name="AmountToHorse" type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label> <span>Amount to Stable</span></label>
                    <input name="AmountToStable" type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is my validation:

```
$('#reloadForm').validate({
                        rules: {

                            AmountToHorse: {
                                required: true,
                                number: true
                            },
                            AmountToStable: {
                                required: true,
                                number: true
                            },
                        }
                    });
```

Any clue on how to do that?

Comment: Post the validation code and the html of the form.

Comment: You would have to write a custom rule using the `.addMethod()` method.  However, before going through the work of writing a detailed answer for you, I'm wondering if you got satisfactory help on [your last question about this plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37515146/594235)?

Comment: @Sparky sorry forgot to accept the other answer. Is done. Appreciate your help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use [the `.addMethod()` method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) to write a custom rule to ensure only one is filled out.

Adjust accordingly...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.validator.addMethod('onlyOne', function(value, element, param) {
        return this.optional(element) || $('[name="' + param[0] + '"]').is(':blank');
    }, "Please fill out only one of these fields");

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            foo: {
                onlyOne: ["bar"],
                number: true
            },
            bar: {
                onlyOne: ["foo"],
                number: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Then use a `blur keyup` handler to ensure the validation messages update themselves on *all* fields.  Again, since I have no idea if you have other fields on this form, adjust these selectors to only target what's relevant and needed.

```
$('input').on('blur keyup', function() {
    $('#myform').valid();  // force validation on entire form
});
```

**Proof-of-Concept DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/e01d5sw7/**

---

**EDIT**:

As per OP's comments, while both fields should not be filled out at the same time, **one field or the other is `required`**...

```
$.validator.addMethod('onlyOne', function(value, element, param) {
    return ($(element).is(':filled') && $('[name="' + param[0] + '"]').is(':blank')) ||
    (($('[name="' + param[0] + '"]').is(':filled')) && $(element).is(':blank'));
}, "Please fill out only one of these fields");
```

**DEMO #2:  http://jsfiddle.net/Lnxxgs92/**

Comment: Works but if you leave empty both then it pass. One must be filled out.

Comment: @VAAA, your OP did not say *"one field out of two is required"*... in fact, you never mentioned that anything was "required".  You said you wanted to *"allow one field"* and that's exactly what my answer is showing.